# Conditions in XML schemas

Tags: xml, xsd

Consider the following (poorly designed?) XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<command_result>
<param name="protocol_version" value="3"/>
<param name="player_state" value="navigator"/>
</command_result>
```

What I want to do is create an XML schema (XSD format) that specifies the datatype of the `value` attribute based on the actual value of the `name` attribute.

Example (pseudocode):

```
if (param name = "protocol_version") then (param value type="xs:integer")
if (param name = "player_state") then (param value type="xs:string")
```

Is there a way, without modifying the source XML, to introduce such a conditional statement in the schema file? I've looked at various solutions, but all of them required changes to the source somehow (e.g. setting xsi:type).

**EDIT**

My current schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="command_result">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="param" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <!-- the following line needs to be modified somehow -->
                        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The only way I can think of is something like this:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="command_result">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <choice>
                    <element name="param" type="tns:protocol_version_type" />
                    <element name="param" type="tns:player_state_type" />
                </choice>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

    <complexType name="protocol_version_type">
        <attribute name="name" type="string" fixed="protocol_version" />
        <attribute name="value" type="integer" />
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="player_state_type">
        <attribute name="name" type="string" fixed="player_state" />
        <attribute name="value" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

But apparently this is not allowed. When I validate this schema in Eclipse, it gives me the following errors:

> - cos-nonambig: "http://www.example.org/schema":param and "http://www.example.org/schema":param (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
> - cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_command_result'. **Multiple elements with name 'param', with different types, appear in the model group.**

As you can see, you can't have two elements with the same name but with a different type. But this is what your XML requires.

**Edit:** You can't even define a simpler schema like this:

```
<element name="command_result">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="param" type="tns:proptocol_version_type" />
            <element name="param" type="tns:type2" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

In this version, no `<choice>` is given, meaning your parameters would have to appear in the given order. But while this removes the `nonambig` error, the `element-consistent`error remains.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :(. Using the same element name for every element seemed like an odd design choice, but it didn't cause too many problems up until now... thanks for trying though.

Comment: I took a break from this problem, but then it suddenly occurred to me that I could just rename the elements to the value in the `name` attribute, then set its value to the value in the `value` attribute. I can create a schema from that which does allow setting the element type for individual elements. Thanks again!

Comment: That seems like a good solution. Of course, it requires you to modify the documents too. But if you can do it, perfect.

Comment: I can't modify the code that generates the XML, but it never crossed my mind that I'm able to modify the XML document before processing it. Still sad that I have to do it this way, but my code looks much cleaner now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to an XSD 1.1 validator, you can use conditional type assignment to specify different bindings for the `param` element based on the values of its `name` attribute.  (The different complex types to which you would bind it would differ mostly in assigning different types to the `value` attribute.)

But in general, you are right:  the use of the same element name for every element is a design choice that simplifies some things, at the cost of hosing your attempts to validate the parameters.